# How to make python read a file to make sure it's fits the restrictions

Tags: python, list, file

I have the code where you read a file called ranks and you have to make sure that the

Rank - Word of Size 15 or less - the Name of the Card

Power - Integer less than 100 - the Power of the Card

Number - Integer less than 100 - the Number of these cards

and then you're supposed to store each of those fields into their own lists. This is what I have so far. I'm not sure how to do the rest.

```
# Reading from a file
numFile = open("ranks.dat", "r")

while True:
    text = numFile.readline()
    text = text.rstrip("\n")     
    if text=="": 
        break
    print (text, end = "\t")


numFile.close()
```

An example of a ranks file could be:

```
Captain,40,2
General,35,1
Lieutenant,25,2
Colonel,20,3
Major,15,2
Admiral,10,5
Corporal,5,6
Sergeant,4,4
Private,1,10
```

Comment: What would you like to happen when a line doesn't meet the restrictions?

Comment: can you show example of how the file looks like?

Comment: @Queuebee, that line shouldn't show up

Comment: @marksman123, an example of how the file looks like is below the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open(file, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        arr = line.split(",")
        if len(arr[0]) > 15:
            # length condition not met, write necessary code here
            pass
        elif int(arr[1]) > 100:
            # power greater than 100, write necessary code here
            pass
        elif int(arr[2]) > 100:
            # number greater than 100, write necessary code here
            pass
```

---

Always use `with` to open a `file` so that you don't have to worry about closing the file.

```
while True:
    ...    
    if text=="":          
        break
```

This is not a good way to read a `file`. Better use `.readlines()` or a loop on the `file`.

Comment: so after it reads the file, how would I add the rank to a list, and the power to another list and the number of cards to another

Comment: You create 3 lists and use `.append()` to add to the list inside the `if/elif`.

Comment: Just a question. Why is pass at the end of the if and elif